# How should you set up an Xcode project that uses storyboards and allows View Controllers to be tested in isolation (and allow rapid iteration)?

Tags: ios, xcode, iteration

I'm developing an app on iOS 8, and using Xcode 6.

Being on iOS, to develop code you have to go through a `Edit -> Compile -> Run -> Verify` cycle.

A problem that I have had pretty much forever is: How do you keep this feedback loop as minimal as possible, regardless of how many levels of navigation your application has?

Consider this example. My application has say, 5 levels of navigation before I can get to the component I would like to develop. For instance:

`Login screen -> Loading screen -> Menu w/ network requests -> Screen with input validation -> Text Editor`

I want to iterate on my `Text Editor` component really quickly.

Due to the number of levels of navigation sequence looks like this.

1. Edit code.
2. Compile code.
3. Run app
4. (Login screen) Login (optional)
5. (Loading screen) Wait a while.
6. (Menu w/ network requests) Select an appropriate item
7. (Screen with input validation) Input data that passes validation
8. (Text Editor) Check that change to text editor has taken effect (e.g. change of font size or some such)

Of course, there are challenges in architecting the app to allow testing in this way, including but not limited to

- how do you supply the view controller under test with test data?
- how do you guarantee the view controller under test, tested in isolation, will look as expected when integrated back into the context of the app itself?

I'm convinced the answer is almost certainly *NOT* functional automated testing (KIF, Subliminal, Calabash et. al.), but some way of breaking the application up into testable units. Not from the perspective of unit testing, but of User Interface testing as well.

i.e. I should be able to tap 'Run' (Cmd + R) and immediately see the editor in action.

Answer (score 0):

For quick iterations, I like to make an Xcode sub-project.  To this by selecting the project file (the blue one), and then doing File->New... project.  In the save window, select "Add to" to place it inside your project.

Then, just add your existing files by reference (make sure not to copy them!).  They will build and run independently of the rest of the larger project.

This is especially useful for testing UI code where creating a functional interface is more difficult than processing the data it displays.  You can mock up some simple objects to provide data for the UI, if needed.

You then do full integration and testing back in your main project.